Invariants on changing locations in coordinate plane
Initially four chips are placed at point $(0,0)$.  At each step we can remove one chip from some point $(a,b)$ and replace it with one at the point $(a+1,b)$ and one at $(a,b+1)$. Show that after finitely many steps, there will always be some point with at least two chips on it.
I let $$f(x)= \frac{1}{2^{a+b}} $$ be the weight of a chip at $(a,b)$ and we can see that
$$f(a,b)=f(a+1,b)+f(a,b+1)$$ and so we can say that the sum is an invariant and that it is equal to
$$4 \cdot \left[ \frac{1}{2^{0+0}} \right]=4.$$
I can't make any further progress, any solution is appreciated.

You are off to a promising start. To conclude, you might view Zvezdelina Stankova's explication of Pebbling a chessboard on YouTube.  The problems are not identical, but close enough that essentially the same proof should work in both cases.

@awkward thanks for recommending the video i completed my proof with a similar argument.

One approach might involve saying that

to get $(0,0)$ down to at most $1$ chip is going to involve at least $3$ chips leaving $(0,0)$ and $3$ chips arriving at $(1,0)$ and $3$ chips arriving at $(0,1)$
to get $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ each down to at most $1$ chip each is going to involve at least $2$ chips leaving $(1,0)$ and $2$ chips leaving $(0,1)$, and $2$ chips  arriving at $(2,0)$ and $2$ chips arriving at $(0,2)$ and $4$ chips arriving at $(1,1)$
so the issue you started with of at least $3$ chips needing to leave $(0,0)$ to get at most $1$ there becomes an issue of at least $3$ chips needing to leave $(1,1)$ to get at most $1$ there plus some other issues
and that will then become the same issue at $(2,2)$ plus some other issues, and then at $(3,3)$ plus some other issues, etc.
but you cannot deal with $3$ chips needing to leave each of an infinite number of positions on the $(a,a)$ diagonal in any finite number of steps.

Notating this:

Write $s(a,b)$ for the number of steps removing a chip from $(a,b)$;

the total number of steps would be $\sum\limits_a \sum\limits_b s(a,b)$.

Then $s(a,b) \ge s(a-1,b)+s(a,b-1)-1$

which implies $s(a,b) \ge ( s(a-2,b)+ s(a-1,b-1)-1)+ (s(a-1,b-1)+s(a,b-2)-1)-1$

so $s(a,b) \ge 2 s(a-1,b-1)-3$.

Since $s(0,0) \ge 3$, this implies $s(1,1)\ge 2 \times 3 -3 =3$

and by induction $s(a,a)\ge 3$ for $a \ge 0$,

so the total number of steps $\sum\limits_a \sum\limits_b s(a,b)$ is infinite.



Yep this could be a strategy i guess, but how can we write a more rigorous solution for this?

You could but it would be longer. I have added this to my answer.

Is s(a,b) no. of steps removing one chip(which is obviously 1) from (a,b) or to make atmost one chip remain.

$s(a,b)$ is  the number of steps acting on the point $(a,b)$ so equal to the number of chips removed from $(a,b)$. For example, you need to reduce the number of chips at $(0,0)$ from $4$ to $0$ or $1$ so $s(0,0)\ge 3$. But that puts at least $3$ chips into $(1,0)$ and into at least $3$ chips into $(0,1)$ so to deal with those issues $s(1,0) \ge 2$ and $s(0,1)\ge 2$. Those steps combined put at least $4$ chips into $(1,1)$ so to deal with that you need $s(1,1)\ge 3$.  And so on.
